# PHP calculations for golf handicap calculator

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a golf handicap calculator setup in wordpress that displays the results as shown below.
Currently this is calculating a handicap based on all rounds played (the score minus the ACR gives the round differential, this is then added together and dived by rounds played and multiplied by 0.93, giving the result).

But I need it to do something like the following:

If user has played between 3-6 rounds, then only use the lowest differential

If user has played between 7-8 rounds, then only use the lowest 2 differentials

If user has played between 9-10 rounds, then only use the lowest 3 differentials 
and so on...

I have each rounds differential stored in a variable called $results as shown below

```
// Begin calculations
        $result = $score - $acr;         //gives each rounds differential   
        array_push($array,$result);      //puts all differentials in array 
        $num = $the_query->found_posts;  //counts number of rounds 
        $av = array_sum($array) / $num;  //calculates average differential
        $round = round($av) * 0.93;      //this is the final handicap
```

Any ideas on how best to achieve this???

[image]

Answer (score 2):

calculate your differentials, sort them lowest to highest. Then use `if()` on number of rounds and take that many differentials that you need according to #of rounds. Do the rest of your math.

Any other answer than that would require writing whole code for you and SO is not that type of site.

Comment: Thanks @Webnet, appreciate the answer. I'm not looking for anyone to write the code, just on the best way to achieve it. Your answer makes sense

Comment: Try implementing this (which sounds quite trivial anyway) and be return if you face any problems with implementation.